# How to use multiple named ui-views

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I have the following states in config file:

```
var home = {
   name: 'home',
   template: '<div ui-view></div>',
   url: '/',
};

var homeSubjects = {
   name: 'home.subjects',
   url: 'Subjects',
   views: {
      '': { templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects.html' },
      'subjects.intro@home.subjects': {
         templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_intro.html',
      },
      'subjects.auth@home.subjects': {
         templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_auth.html',
      }
  }
};

var homeSubjectsSubjectExams = {
   name: 'home.subjects.exams',
   url: '/Exams',
   views: {
      '': { templateUrl: 'app/exams/partials/exams.html'},
      'exams.intro@home.subjects.exams': {
         templateUrl: 'app/exams/partials/exams_intro.html',
      },
      'exams.auth@home.subjects.exams': {
         templateUrl: 'app/exams/partials/exams_auth.html',
      },
   }
}
```

In my `index.html` file i have the following code:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

In `subjects.html` I have:

```
<div id="subject">
   <div class="intro" ui-view="subjects.intro"></div>
   <div class="auth" ui-view="subjects.auth"></div>
</div>
<div ui-view></div> // <--- I want the exams.html to appear here
```

In my `exams.html` I have:

```
<div id="exams">
    <div class="intro" ui-view="exams.intro"></div>
    <div class="auth" ui-view="exams.auth"></div>
</div>
```

I want the exams.html to appear below the subject.html page. Anyone has any idea how am I supposed to go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be almost there. The example as is is working.

There is [a plunker with that](http://plnkr.co/edit/YXKmRuVI1w43FIC8Ppl6?p=preview) all - AS IS.

I did not change almost anyhting *(just use template instead of templateUrl to make it more simple)*:

```
.state('home.subjects', {
    name: 'home.subjects',
    url: 'Subjects',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects.html'
      },
      'subjects.intro@home.subjects': {
        //templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_intro.html',
        template: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_intro.html',
      },
      'subjects.auth@home.subjects': {
        //templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_auth.html',
        template: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_auth.html',
      }
    }
})

.state('home.subjects.exams', {
  name: 'home.subjects.exams',
  url: '/Exams',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'app/exams/partials/exams.html'
    },
    'exams.intro@home.subjects.exams': {
      //templateUrl: 'app/exams/partials/exams_intro.html',
      template: 'app/exams/partials/exams_intro.html',
    },
    'exams.auth@home.subjects.exams': {
      //templateUrl: 'app/exams/partials/exams_auth.html',
      template: 'app/exams/partials/exams_auth.html',
    },
  }
})
```

And this is the result if we go to `<a ui-sref="home.subjects.exams">`

```
app/subjects/partials/subjects_intro.html
app/subjects/partials/subjects_auth.html
app/exams/partials/exams_intro.html
app/exams/partials/exams_auth.html
```

As we can see, the `home.subjects` is on page, and below is injected `exams` substate

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YXKmRuVI1w43FIC8Ppl6?p=preview)